# View based iPhone application Subview removing?

Tags: iphone, ios, view

I'M in trouble.

I'm adding other views like this.

```
haberdetay *detayview = [[haberdetay alloc] initWithNibName:@"haberdetay" bundle:nil];

CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.25;
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

[self.view addSubview:detayview.view];
```

This view opens another view and another maybe. Then user touches the main icon. This all views are using memory. How can I delete them. I'm trying

```
NSArray * subviews = [self.view subviews];
for(UIView * aSubview in subviews)
{
    // this removes and releases the subviews you allocated
    [aSubview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

This access haberdetay's subviews but I must access all subviews to remove or access them.

As you know, i'm confused :) If you understand me, please tell me, how can I do? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use either pushViewController or presentModalViewController instead of adding a view of one Viewcontroller in another Viewcontroller and when you want to come back you can use popViewController or dismissModalViewController, this helps in memory management as well.

Comment: mainwindow has view based viewcontroller, I will change it to navigation view controller. And this methods will run perfectly, right? Last one, Should I add navigation controller to other xib files?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [self.navigationController pushViewController: haberdetay animated: YES];  that will cache your previous view, so it won't have to be released. It will also handle the animations, and the adding and removing of the main views for you.  And besides, it's a REALLY bad idea to flush a view like that, especially the main self.view.

Comment: I got it, thanks. I'm trying like this. Should I alloc haberdetay?

Comment: No problem.  Always alloc and init when there are no convenience methods.